# what is the issue i am Not able to open the native player to play the recorded file?

Tags: android

This is my code.what i am using?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DEFAULT);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(fileName), "audio/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

It is giving error

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Hitesh_2011-04-19Time10-55.amr typ=audio/* }
```

is there any permission to use native player.what is the issue?

plz help me.plz
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

i dont get what do you mean by native player. but still this is the code that i have used to play a local file in the sdcard using the default player.

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

        Uri data = Uri.parse("file://"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath()+"/" + fileName);
        String type = "audio/mp3";
        intent.setDataAndType(data, type);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Hope it helps and let me know the output of it.

Comment: thanks its wrks.but if we manually delete the file from sdcard than i should give the msg that file not exists.then what should i do for it

Comment: in that case you can check for the existence of the file before setting to intents data. can use `file.exists() and it returns true if this file exists, false otherwise`