# Android play AMR file using default Music player

Tags: android, android-intent

I have few AMR file in my SD card. I want to play those amr files using default android music player.
TODO this,i tried below code :

```
        Uri myUri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/myfiles/filename.amr");
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(myUri, "audio/*");
    startActivity(intent);
```

and my stacktrace :

`07-16 15:23:47.284: D/Instrumentation(32496): checkStartActivityResult  :Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=/storage/emulated/0/myfiles/filename.amr typ=audio/* }

07-16 15:23:47.284: D/Instrumentation(32496): checkStartActivityResult  inent is instance of inent:  07-16 15:23:47.284: D/AndroidRuntime(32496): Shutting down VM

07-16 15:23:47.284: W/dalvikvm(32496): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414feac8)

07-16 15:23:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(32496): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

07-16 15:23:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(32496): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW   dat=/storage/emulated/0/myfiles/filename.amr typ=audio/* }

07-16 15:23:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(32496):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1659)

07-16 15:23:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(32496):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1434)

07-16 15:23:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(32496):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3430)

07-16 15:23:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(32496):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3391)

07-16 15:23:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(32496):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3626)

07-16 15:23:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(32496):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3594)
07-16 15:23:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(32496):    at com.example.ui.MainActivity.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:85)

07-16 15:23:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(32496):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:301)

07-16 15:23:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(32496):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1502)

07-16 15:23:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(32496):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3250)
07-16 15:23:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(32496):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:4299) 
07-16 15:23:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(32496):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)    07-16 15:23:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(32496):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-16 15:23:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(32496):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-16 15:23:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(32496):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)

07-16 15:23:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(32496):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

07-16 15:23:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(32496):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
07-16 15:23:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(32496):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
07-16 15:23:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(32496):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 
07-16 15:23:47.304: E/AndroidRuntime(32496):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

How can i achieve this ?
When this amr is opened in file manager,it shows a dialog to choose music players available and started playing.Same thing i want to achieve.

[image: my target to achieve to get this pop up in my app]

Comment: Any Intent Action and category needed?

Comment: @NitZRobotKoder i followed this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265893/how-to-start-the-default-music-player-from-my-app

Answer (score 0):

Try to set mimeType as "audio/amr" instead of "audio/*".
Probably you also have to do
    "file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()

See here: [what is the issue i am Not able to open the native player to play the recorded file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712341/what-is-the-issue-i-am-not-able-to-open-the-native-player-to-play-the-recorded-f)